# what scope of a bean before conversation.begin method is called

Tags: scope, cdi

I have a CDI bean:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable{
      @Inject
      private Conversation converstion;

      private void conversationBegin() {
          converstion.begin();
      }
}
```

My question is:
what scope of this bean before `conversationBegin()` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're thinking about CDI wrong.

You hold a **contextual reference** to a bean with type MyBean.  When you use it, a **contextual instance** is either created or obtained from the active conversation context and proxied by your contextual reference.

There is no change of scope. The only thing that changes over time is which context is active and whether there are instances already in the context or not.

Comment: So, why do we need to call converstion.begin() method? what for?

Comment: I don't know much JSF, but here is what CDI 1.0 has to say about it:
"""
Any conversation is in one of two states: transient or long-running.

    By default, a conversation is transient

    A transient conversation may be marked long-running by calling Conversation.begin()
I
    A long-running conversation may be marked transient by calling Conversation.end()
...
"""

Comment: "By default, a conversation is transient". Not exactly but i can understant that it is like RequestScoped. That thing is that i want to ask. It also means: if Conversation.begin() method is never called, that bean is RequestScoped. How do you think?

Comment: From the CDI spec, I think that is fair, since a transient conversation is explicitly destroyed at the end of the request.

Comment: No, it's still ConversationScoped, just that the length of that instance of a context (the conversation context in this case) happens to be the same duration of a RequestScoped object. If it helps to think of it as a RequestScoped bean, that's fine, but you cannot change context of a Bean (Bean being the CDI definition of a bean).

Comment: Whoops, should not have agreed to that.  Only in a very fudged way "request scoped" but not RequestScoped